# How to replace dictionary key value based on its index

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to replace dictionary values based on their index

Ex:

```
mydict = {'abc':10, 'iji':9, 'sls': 8, 'eie': 2, 'wlw': 6, 'pwp': 5}
```

Here i need to replace the value of the key at 4th index with new value 10

Expected output:

```
{'abc':10, 'iji':9, 'sls': 8, 'eie': 2, 'wlw': 10, 'pwp': 5}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`dict.keys()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#dict.keys) to get the keys of the dictionary, then find the key at the 4th index of that list and set that value in the dictionary:

```
mydict = {'abc':10, 'iji':9, 'sls': 8, 'eie': 2, 'wlw': 6, 'pwp': 5}

keys = list(mydict.keys())
mydict[keys[4]] = 10

print(mydict)
```

Output:

```
{'abc': 10, 'iji': 9, 'sls': 8, 'eie': 2, 'wlw': 10, 'pwp': 5}
```

**Note**

This will only work in Python < 3.7 if the dictionary is not modified (entries added or deleted after creation) as otherwise `mydict.keys()` is not guaranteed to return the same order of result each time. For versions of Python < 3.7 it is safer to use an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=ordereddict#collections.OrderedDict).

Comment: An important consideration is that the ordering of the keys is only guaranteed to be preserved from Python 3.7 onwards. An OrderedDict provides this guarantee in other versions.

Comment: @Kemp I don't believe that affects this code. Once the dictionary is created, unless an entry is added/removed the key ordering should remain the same, so the value of `mydict.keys()` should be a constant. But I will add a note.